# Does "in the past" mean the same things as "before"?

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

> I have been there a few times in the past.

Would it be equal to:

> I have been there a few times before.

Comment: Any reason why you think it might not be?

Answer (score 1):

When you name the exact tense as present perfect all you need to say, "I have been there." No harm in saying "I have been there before a few times." The time of "being there" is not important. When a friend whom you visit at his home says to you, "Join me for a lunch of pastrami sandwich and ice tea." And you came after you had lunch. There is no need to say anything but, "I have already eaten."

I have been there *a few times in the past* is superfluous. You could not have been there in the future so, if you feel like giving extra information that is OK.

Answer (score 1):

No they do not have the same meaning, except in certain contexts.

*I have been there a few times in the past* means that you have been there a few times before the present time.
*I have been there a few times before* means that you have been there a few times before a time previously mentioned in the conversation.

So it is common to hear constructions like:
*I have been there a few times before and many times since.*

Of course, if no previous time was mentioned in the conversation, then *before* will refer to the present and both sentences will then have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they both have the same meaning. Usually the second example is more common in conversation.